# Logit-lasso + missing values + numeric variables (with less than 2 levels)

Tags: logistic, missing-data, lasso

Does anyone know a way to compute a **rigorous logit lasso** such that it is possible to introduce variables with some **NA's** or **less than 2 levels**?

Any clue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "less than two levels" and what "rigorous" is intended to imply.